# How to give values to items in a list in prolog

Tags: prolog

So i made a list using `atom_chars(X,Y).` Which split the string `'abc'` into `[a,b,c]`. I now want to assign numbers to the elements in the list. Such as `a` is 4, `b` is 2, `c` is 7.

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: you need uppercase letters to name a variable, but atom_chars gives you characters when give you uppercase string, so which cannot be done. But if you pass a list of variables, you can assign values to them.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

In Prolog, the symbols `a`, `b`, and `c` are considered *atoms*. You can't "assign" values to them. You could, however, associate numbers with them using, for example, `-` as a convenient notation for a term. You could form a list:

```
[a-2, b-4, c-3]
```

Let's say you bind this to the variable `AssocList`. Then if you have a letter or character bound to `C`, you can query:

```
member(C-N, AssocList)
```

This will bind `N` to the number associated with `C`. Likewise, if you have a number, it will yield all of the characters `C` that are associated with that number.