# Iterating through 2D list in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to iterate through a 2D list in prolog. So let's assume we have a list of

`[item(Key,Value), ......., (item(Key,Value)]`

I know we can go through a list by omitting the head element through:

```
member2(X, [H|T]):-
    member2(X, T).
```

But i do not know how to iterate through the Key/Value list.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `member2(Key, Value, List) :- member(item(Key, Value), List).`?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this question and answer: [How to give values to items in a list in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59120632/how-to-give-values-to-items-in-a-list-in-prolog/59129596#59129596). For key value pairs, the most convenient notation is `Key-Value`.

Comment: This is not a 2D list. It's a 1D list of key-value pairs. `item(Key, Value)` is not  a list. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to search if Key is present in the list or not. If yes then I have linked the code below.

```
searchKey(Key,[(Key,Value)|_]):- write(Key) , write('-->'), write(Value) , !.
searchKey(Key,[_|T]):- searchKey(Key,T).
```

**OUTPUT**

```
?- searchKey(3,[(1,99),(2,98),(3,97),(4,96)]).
3-->97
```

if you search for a element that doesnt exist then it wil return false.

```
?- searchKey(5,[(1,99),(2,98),(3,97),(4,96)]).
   false
```

Hope this helped you. If this is not what you've asked. Then try explaining the question more clearly.

Comment: You don't really need all of that. If you have a `Key` just check `member((Key, Value), KeyValueList)` and it will either fail (the key doesn't exist) or it will instantiate the `Value` for the corresponding `Key`.

Comment: Got your point. But I was trying to explain how it works. Defining his own search or membership function. For beginners implementing in-built functions on their own helps increase their knowledge.